# How to reduce PNG size in ios for email sharing

Tags: iphone, ios, email, png

now I am trying share PNG file on my app.

I opened 2 MB png on my app and share that png by email on my app.

but, email said that image size is 20 MB.

how can I reduce PNG size for email sharing?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using JPEG, PNG is designed for quality, not size.

Are you creating a UIImage or reading directly from file?

If you are absolutely sure that it is the correct size beforehand, and that it is being resize, read the file directly with NSData from file and add the octects to the attachment stream, but JPEG would be nicer for size.

Comment: Thanks, but, i need a png sharing because some peoples need share a transparent background image. when share jpeg, that is not transparent background. So, I need share a PNG. I made that png from UIImagePNGRepresentation.

Comment: I see. It looks like the encoding of the UIImage is less than optimal, it might be the colour space or size. Is it ok to use the file that is stored on disk?